# how to check wether a document is completed in web control

Tags: c#

i m using webbrowser control in my c# application but the document_completed fun is called for three times and i implemented my logics in this function.i want to check wether a document is loaded or not load in webbrowser control how can i check it or can i call this function from another function.

Comment: document_completed is an event and not a function that you can call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event is raised once for each referenced document that has been loaded, which means that for example external CSS files, images and frameset documents will cause the event to be raised as well as the main page.

You can check the `Url` property of the [`WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserdocumentcompletedeventargs.aspx) that is passed to the event handler to see which resource or page that the event refers to. That way, you can avoid executing your logic multiple times per request.

Comment: Old question but just the answer I needed today. Thanks.  +1.